# FIS_AUTH_ERROR in FirebaseMessaging on physical device

Tags: android, firebase

I added firebase to the application

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.0')     
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.3.0'     
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:23.2.0'
```

Added getting a token in MainActivity

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Fetching FCM registration token failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@OnCompleteListener
            }
            val token = task.result
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
```

Everything works on the emulator.
I can't get a token on a physical device. Tried on different devices

```
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(FirebaseMessaging.java:637)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$getToken$4$com-google-firebase-messaging-FirebaseMessaging(FirebaseMessaging.java:393)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$$ExternalSyntheticLambda10.run(Unknown Source:4)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:463)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:5)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:8)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(FirebaseMessaging.java:635)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$getToken$4$com-google-firebase-messaging-FirebaseMessaging(FirebaseMessaging.java:393) 
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$$ExternalSyntheticLambda10.run(Unknown Source:4) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:463) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) 
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637) 
at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
```

Tried on different devices

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does the tested devices have `GMS` / `Google Playstore` installed?